# HTML/CSS resize text embed to content size

Tags: html, css, text, embed

I have a `<embed>` element inside a div that contains a .txt file and I want to set it to automatically fit the size of the txt files contents.

However none of the tips I found here seem to work.

height: 100% or auto does absolutely nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Testpage</title>
      <style>
         body {
            background: #aaa;
         }
         div {
            width: 800px;
            background: white;
         }
         embed {
            padding: 25px;
            width: 750px;
            height: 100%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <embed src="file.txt">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Also using `<object>` instead of `<embed>` as suggested in many questions here doesn't change the behavior at all.

It can't be that hard to do something this basic in CSS?

Comment: _“It can't be that hard to do something this basic in CSS?”_ - Don’t worry, it’s not _hard_ - it is just _impossible_. You are _creating_ a barrier CSS can not reach across here, but not making this content part of your actual document to begin with, but embedding it as an external resource instead. This is basically the same, as if you had used an iframe - and those don’t adapt to their content automatically either, nor can they be persuaded to do so via CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe can try to use the `font-size` property of CSS.
An example of usage with it:

```
embed {
font-size: *what you need here*;
width: 100%;
}
```

Otherwise you may wanna look into CSS properties in JavaScript, and read lines, length etc. of content and base of it and take the users screen width into fact for the best result!

**EDIT:**

You could use XMLHttpRequest, AJAX, jQuery aswell in JavaScript.
And then change font size based on length of content.

Comment: I found another way where I don't have to deal with the embed or object elements.
I just read in the filecontents with php and echo them inside a pre element to keep the layout.
Much easier.

Comment: Ah ok, I could've gived XMLHttpRequest() example, with JS. But you seem to have solved it by reading content and echoing with PHP! :)